# How to use a variable of unix at Bteq Script?

Tags: linux, unix, teradata

I am creating a Frame work at Unix . This frame Work calls multiple DML's at different different Stages according to the dynamic situations.

All DML's contain set of sql queries. Each query comes under a defined Lable (Say Lable 1 .... Lable 2.... etc)
I want to make this framework so good so that it can trigger the DML from the required LABEL only ....(In case of Failure and restart job).. 
So for that i need to take the Unix variable($LABLE) inside the DML's.

I am not getting ...how to do this???
Please help !!!! if you ever try this.....

Sample DML -

```
.LOGON TDPS/admin_dxwx_p05,store123;

.LABEL FIRST
CREATE SET TABLE DXWX_P05_DLWORK_DB01.WorKTable_1 ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
      Customer_Name VARCHAR(25) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      Age INTEGER,
      Product_Name VARCHAR(25) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      Price INTEGER)
PRIMARY INDEX ( Customer_Name );
.IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .GOTO ERRORFOUND

.LABEL SECOND
CREATE SET TABLE DXWX_P05_DLWORK_DB01.WorkTable_2 ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
      Customer_Name VARCHAR(25) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      Age INTEGER
      Product_Name VARCHAR(25) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      Price INTEGER)
PRIMARY INDEX ( Customer_Name );
.IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .GOTO ERRORFOUND

.LABEL THIRD
Insert into DXWX_P05_DLWORK_DB01.WorKTable_1
Sel * from 
DXWX_P05_DLWORK_DB01.Source_Table;
.IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .GOTO ERRORFOUND

.LABEL FOUR
Insert into DXWX_P05_DLWORK_DB01.WorKTable_2
Sel * from 
DXWX_P05_DLWORK_DB01.WorKTable_1;
.IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .GOTO ERRORFOUND

.QUIT 0;

.label ERRORFOUND
.QUIT 8;

  .LOGOFF;
EOF
```

Comment: You want to dynamically decide what label to execute, basically?

Comment: You can embed your entire BTEQ script in a shell script and then your variable substitution will work automagically. We do this in our environment often and it makes things like environment substitution (DEV, TST, PRD) in the database name a breeze.